# How to add associative array to the newly created array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've an array titled `$val`. It's a blank array. I want it in following manner i.e. after `print_r($val);` it should print the array `$val` in following manner:

I've following variables too :

```
$_POST['fileName'] = 'Sample_1.docx';
$_POST['fileLink'] = 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/HEYQ6lPNRg2lzjUNhUGX';

Array
(
    [status_info] => 
    [user_status] => Share what's going on...
    [group_id] => 
    [action] => upload_photo_via_share
    [is_activity_feed] => 1
    [vshare] => Array
        (
            [Sample_1.docx] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/HEYQ6lPNRg2lzjUNhUGX
                )

        )

    [link] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://
        )

    [poll_question] => 
    [answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [answer] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [answer] => 
                )

        )

    [is_profile] => no
    [iframe] => 1
    [method] => simple
    [document_title] => document
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [code_snippet] => 
)
```

I want to add following structure to the variable `$val`. This thing should be done using PHP code only.

How should I add following structure of key-values to the array `$val` in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP source of this array should be like this:

```
$val = array(
    'status_info' => '',
    'user_status' => 'Share what's going on...',
    ...     
    'vshare' => array(
        'Sample_1.docx' => array (
            'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/HEYQ6lPNRg2lzjUNhUGX'
        )
    ),

    'link' => array(
        'url' => 'http://'
    ), 

    ...
);
```

Comment: I want the output as above but how to do it in PHP code? That's my issue. Please help me in it.

Comment: @PHPNut: here is the array, `print_r($val)` makes you an input as you have above.